# Given a 2-variable function, prove that: $xz * z'_x-yz*z'_y = -\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I'm kinda new to this material and was having a hard time solving this exercise, can anyone please show me the correct way of solving this?

Let $z(x,y)$ be an equation that satisfies:
$ z^2+ln(x)+xy+xe^{z^2+1}=1 $

Prove that: $xz * z'_x-yz*z'_y = -\frac{1}{2}$

Thanks

Comment: Well I first tried to take $z'_x$ and $z'_y$ using the definition of derivative and tried to multiply them to make them look like the second equation, but I got a mess so I assume my derivative is not good

Comment: That should be the correct approach. If you could write out your steps, we will help you to figure out the mistake.